# How can the GGA functionals in libxc be evaluated?

Tags: density-functional-theory, software, exchange-correlation, libxc

For pedagogical reasons, I started adding [libxc](https://www.tddft.org/programs/libxc/) to the atomic DFT [dftatom](https://github.com/certik/dftatom). In this program only spherical symmetric charges. That means that the final potential is just radial.

To my understanding, if the LDA xc energy is defined as

$$
E_{xc}[n(r)] = \int n(\mathbf{r}) \varepsilon_{xc}[n(\mathbf{r})]\ d\mathbf{r},
$$
the radial xc potential contribution will be
$$
V_{xc}[n(r)] = \varepsilon_{xc}(r) + n(r)\,\frac{d \varepsilon_{xc}(r)}{d n(r)}
$$

According to the manual of libxc from the function with the interface

```
void xc_lda_exc_vxc(const xc_lda_type *p, inp np, double *rho, 
     double *exc, double *vrho);
```

the $\varepsilon_{xc}$ from `exc` and $\frac{d \varepsilon_{xc}}{d n}$ from `vrho`. Judging from comparison to simple analytical expressions (e.g. Slater exchange), I would say the `vrho` actually returns the whole radial expression $\varepsilon_{xc} + n\frac{d \varepsilon_{xc}}{d n}$ already.

I am starting to wonder is the gradient correction term for GGA returned from the interface. Generally, GGA potential is written as

$$
V_{xc}[n] = \varepsilon_{xc} + n\frac{\partial \varepsilon_{xc}}{\partial n} - \nabla\cdot\left[n\frac{\partial \varepsilon_{xc}}{\partial \nabla n}\right].
$$

and with the contracted gradient $\sigma$

$$
V_{xc}[n] = \varepsilon_{xc} + n\frac{\partial \varepsilon_{xc}}{\partial n} - 2 \, \nabla\cdot\left[n\frac{\partial \varepsilon_{xc}}{\partial \sigma} \nabla n\right].
$$

The interface for GGA is

```
void xc_gga_exc_vxc(const xc_func_type *p, int np, double *rho, double *sigma, 
     double *exc, double *vrho, double *vsigma)
```

Also here I would say that `vrho` returns the sum of the first two terms and `vsigma` is $n\frac{\partial \varepsilon_{xc}}{\partial \sigma}$.

Can somebody verify the correct implementation for GGA and LDA from the libxc functions?

Comment: Maybe talking directly to the libxc developers like @susi-lehtola can help.

Comment: Possibly answered here: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/3650/how-does-libxc-calculate-the-potential-of-gga-functionals

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The xc energy is given by

$$ E_\text{xc} = \int n({\bf r}) \epsilon_\text{xc} ({\bf r}) {\rm d}^3r \equiv \int f_\text{xc} ({\bf r}) {\rm d}^3r $$

where $\epsilon_\text{xc}$ is the energy density *per particle* and $f_\text{xc}$ is the energy density. What Libxc gives you is $\epsilon_\text{xc}$ and derivatives of $f_\text{xc}$, such as $\partial f_\text{xc} / \partial n_\sigma$, $\partial f_\text{xc} / \partial \gamma_{\sigma \sigma'}$, $\partial f_\text{xc} / \partial \nabla^2 n_\sigma$, and $\partial f_\text{xc} / \partial \tau_\sigma$ that you need for e.g. self-consistent field calculations.

How you actually use these variables depends on the numerical approach. The approach you have described above is the one based on a real-space potential $v({\bf r})$, which is simple for the LDA but gets a bit hairy already for GGAs since you need to evaluate the divergence of a term that contains both the density and the density functional.

If you have a basis set, you can use integration by parts to get rid of the divergences and end up with a straightforward quadrature problem as discussed e.g. in our recent open access review article: [Molecules 25, 1218 (2020)](https://doi.org/10.3390/molecules25051218). This also works nicely with numerical basis sets, as I've demonstrated e.g. in [Int. J. Quantum Chem. 119, e25945 (2019)](https://doi.org/10.1002/qua.25945).

If you have a basis set, you can also evaluate the real-space potential $v({\bf r})$ in an analytical fashion. This leads to higher-order derivatives of $f_\text{xc}$ which are also provided by Libxc as well as derivatives of the density; I have demonstrated this for atoms in [Phys. Rev. A 101, 012516 (2020)](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevA.101.012516).

In contrast, as far as I know, programs employing the finite difference approach like dftatom evaluate the GGA contribution to the potential by finite differences.